# sql query with date comparing in where clause

Tags: sql

Hi I have a table with four columns id, name, start_date, end_date.

Below is the stored procedure that I tried to retrieve the rows from the table.

I will be passing @status as a parameter which will be having values ( 1 for active, 2 for inactive, and null)

```
Alter procedure dbo.GetName(@id int, @statusDate VARCHAR(50))
begin 
select id, name  from customer 
where id = @id 
AND ((@statusDate  = 1 AND GETDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
    OR (@statusDate = 2 AND GETDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) 
    OR @statusDate IS NULL)
end
```

Condition is

- if @statusDate  is 1 then retrieve row which has todays date between start and end date
- if @statusDate  is 2 then retrieve row which does not has todays date between start and end date
- if @statusDate  is null then retrieve all row

Please help me in modifying the and condition so that it retrieves the rows based on the above condition

Comment: what results are you getting with your query? Whats wrong with them?

Comment: I have added sample rows that has start_date and end_date as future dates. If I execute the query by passing @statusDate as 1 I still get rows retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a question in there somewhere?

If your data set is small (and small depends on the hardware supporting it), then your above query seems fine (except for the logical error in your second condition; see below).  If yyou start experiencing performance issues, you may want to use conditional blocks, like so (this syntax is for Microsoft SQL Server):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetName
    (
      @id INT
    , @statusDate BIT
    )
AS 
    BEGIN

        IF @StatusDate IS NULL 
            BEGIN
                SELECT  id
                      , name
                FROM    customer
                WHERE   id = @id
            END


        IF @statusDate = 1 
            BEGIN
                SELECT  id
                      , name
                FROM    customer
                WHERE   id = @id
                        AND GETDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

            END


        IF @statusDate = 2 
            BEGIN
                SELECT  id
                      , name
                FROM    customer
                WHERE   id = @id
                        AND ( GETDATE() < start_date
                              OR GETDATE() > end_date
                            )
            END

    END
```

Comment: re edited the question..Please help me in modifying the 'and' condition and the query so that it satisfies my search condition

Comment: Are your passing @status or @statusdate?  Did you look at the sample I posted? What was the error message you got 9if any), or why doesn't it satisfy the search condition?

Comment: I am passing @statusDate. Actually i have big search criteria where one of the condition is the above. so i feel better if it is solved in my 'and ' where class

Comment: k, then your code should work, but you are missing either a NOT or an exclusion; look at the IF @Statusdate=2 query at the WHERE clause.

Comment: Hi my code is working fine but if end_date is today's date then it should come under active but this query is considering it as active

Answer (score 0):

Try to put null check at the beginning of where clause like this:

```
select id, name  from customer 
where id = @id 
AND ((@statusDate IS NULL)
    OR (@statusDate  = 1 AND GETDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date)
    OR (@statusDate = 2 AND NOT GETDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date))
```

Your clause is always null if @statusDate is null, so no records are selected because of it

Comment: i am getting the same results if i change to above statement

Comment: I haven't noticed condition if @statusDate=2. I've edited query to match it. Try it again

Comment: Hi mao, if end_date or start_date is today's date then it should come under active will this query work for me?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT id, name 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE id = @id 
      AND @statusDate  = 1 
      AND GETDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

UNION ALL

    SELECT id, name 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE id = @id 
      AND @statusDate  = 2 
      AND GETDATE() NOT BETWEEN start_date AND end_date

UNION ALL

    SELECT id, name 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE id = @id 
      AND @statusDate IS NULL
```